# Question about birth and disaster models

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

We haven't covered birth and death processes yet in class, and my teacher gave us questions to try over spring break.

I was hoping to get a head start so I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to do this!

A birth or disaster model is a chain with states $0,1,2,...$ such that at state $j$ you either move to $j+1$ with probability $p_j$ or drop down to zero with probability $q_j = 1-p_j$.  From zero you go to $1$ with probability $1$.

a) Show that all states are recurrent if and only if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {P_1 \cdot P_2 \cdot P_3 \cdot\cdot\cdot P_n} = 0$$

b) Assume the chain is recurrent, and show that all states are null recurrent if and only if the sum $ 1 + P_1 + P_1P_2 + P_1P_2P_3 + ...$ diverges.

I'm not quite sure how to get started on these questions - any help?  Many thanks!

Comment: Well, first you want to compute the probability that you get back to zero, given you are in state 0.  Can you compute that? Or 1 minus that?

Comment: Well, can you describe what has to happen if we never get back to zero? What infinite chain of events?

Comment: If we never get back to zero, then there would just be an infinite chain of one-step transition probabilities from one step to the next, right?

Comment: Yes, in fact, we never get back to zero if and only if there is an infinite chain of one-step transitions to the right, and so the probability we never get back to zero is...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21566/discussion-on-question-by-rex7878-question-about-birth-and-disaster-models).

Answer (score 0):

For a):

The chain is irreducible. To see this consider arbitrary states *i*, *j*. It's easy to show that states *i* and *j* communicate if you think about what sequence of transitions are needed to move from state *i* to *j*, and vice versa.

This is helpful because you can show that recurrence is a class property, and so if any state is recurrent, they all are.

Consider state zero, $E_0$. $E_0$ is recurrent iff the probability of ever returning to $E_0$, given that you start at $E_0$ is one. The complement of this event is that you never return to $E_0$ starting at $E_0$. The only way to do this is to move forward down the chain to positive infinity.

Concretely:

$P(\{ \text{Ever return to state $E_0$ from $E_0$} \}) $

= 1 - $P(\{ \text{Never return to state $E_0$ from $E_0$} \})$

= 1- $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}  \{X_1 = 1\} \cap \{X_2 = 2\} \cap ... \{X_n = n\} | X_0 = 0)$

= 1 - $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\{X_1 = 1\} \cap \{X_2 = 2\} \cap ... \{X_n = n\}| X_0 = 0)$

= 1 - $\lim_{n\to\infty}  P(X_n = n | X_{n-1} = n-1)*P(X_{n-1} = n-1 |X_{n-2} = n-2)* ... *P(X_1 = 1 |X_0 = 0)$ *(By Markov Property)*

= 1 - $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pi_{i=0}^n{P_i}$.

Therefore $P(\{ \text{Ever return to state $E_0$ from $E_0$} \})  = 1 $  (and thus the whole chain is recurrent) iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pi_{i=0}^n{P_i}$ = 0.

---

for b)

It can be shown that null recurrence is a class property. Therefore it suffices to show that any state is null recurrent to show that they all, because this chain is irreducible.

Consider state $E_0$. $E_0$ is null recurrent iff the *mean return time* is infinite, i.e $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n*f_{0,0}^n = \infty$. The structure of the chain makes only one way to return to $E_0$ from $E_0$ in $k$ steps possible (forward k-1 steps, backwards one.) If you write out sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n*f_{0,0}^n$, you should be able to see the result.